# filter items by relational count in directus

Tags: directus

I'm playing around with Directus and wanted to filter my items by counting O2M relations.
I tried using `has`, but as [described in docs](https://docs.directus.io/api/query/filter.html#filter-relational) it counts "at least n items", but I want to retrieve all items with a relation count of `0`. How can I achieve this?

Having two tables:

[image]

My current request is like this:

`https://directus.localhost/_/items/products?meta=total_count,result_count&limit=100&offset=0&fields=id,suppliers.*&filter[suppliers][has]=0`

But I get all products, since all do have at least 0 suppliers. How to filter exactly zero suppliers?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Hello,
Did you manage to implement it?
I want to a similar operations except I want to exclude all those with zero child collection

Comment: Yes I did. 2 possible solutions: either build a custom endpoint or fetch data and reduce them as you need. Sadly there is nothing like a "build in" way.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure about the structure of your data. But I had the problem in the past that I wanted to filter for all files which has no link to a folder. What at the end worked for me was something like this:

```
&filter[suppliers][_null]=true
```